# Powers of 2 with while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

My program is supposed to take an input and output powers of 2. For example input 8, and output 1,2,4,8,16,32,65,128. However, instead of doing the 8 integers and outputting each *2, it only goes up to when it hits the number 8 and stops. I do not want to use the ** operator.

```
limit=input('Enter a value for limit')
limit =int(limit)
ctr=1
while ctr <= (limit):
    print(ctr, end=' ')
    ctr=ctr*2
print("limit=", limit)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ctr` is the value, not the number of times you've performed the operation. Use `range` instead, and use more appropriate variable names for clarity:

```
limit = input('Enter a value for limit: ')
limit = int(limit)
result = 1
for _ in range(limit):
    print(result, end=' ')
    result *= 2

print()
print(f"limit={limit}")
```

Result:

```
Enter a value for limit: 8
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 
limit=8
```

You can emulate a `for` loop and `range` with a `while` loop as follows, although I wouldn't recommend it:

```
ctr = 0
while ctr < limit:
    print(result, end=' ')
    result *= 2
    ctr += 1
```

Comment: For what I am doing, it needs to be in a while loop. Despite for being the better way of going about it

Comment: @Mo_The_User - You can certainly do that with a `while` loop, but `for _ in range(n):` is the normal way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @tigerhawkt3 is the best one, but if you want a while loop you could do like this:

```
limit = input('Enter a value for limit')
limit = int(limit)
ctr = 1
i = 0

while i < (limit):
    print(ctr, end=' ')
    ctr *= 2
    i += 1

print("limit=", limit)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. However, how come if I was to put in 8, it stops at 256 instead of 128?

Comment: replace '<=' to '<'.